# Using Drupal 7, how do you add fields to images, similar to imagefield_extended in D6?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-7, imagefield

I'm attempting to add an additional field to images.
e.g. position, left or right.

So the user can add multiple images and specify left or right position.

In Drupal 6, one would use imagefield_extended or cck multigroup.

Using Drupal 7, how do you add fields associated with images?

The user should be able to reorder these images and their associated data on the node/add or node/edit screen.

Comment: Are you using image fields associated with a node? It's my understanding that fields can only be associated with entities, such as nodes, users, files, and comments. You might need to create a separate image node type, associate the fields with that, then use node reference to associate it with your content.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://drupal.org/project/field_collection, that might be want you are looking for.

Put simply, field_collection is a field to which you can attach fields. So you could create a field, add an image field to it and any number of other fields which are then automatically grouped.

There is also the media project, which exposes an media entity which can be an image and you can directly attach fields to: http://drupal.org/project/media

Comment: I tried field_collection. I have a couple issues with it.

1. you must create the node and then add images & data on the node view page.

2. there is no easy way to reorder the images.

While Media looks like a promising module I think it is a little heavy for this use case. 

Thank you for your effort. +1 :)